# Syntax highlighting code fragments

Tags: beamer, minted

I am trying to split a long code listing into two columns, on a Beamer slide, using Minted. However, because the second column isn't syntactically valid (i.e., without the lead in from the first), Pygments is highlighting the errors.

```
\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{minted}{json}
{
  "this": "is valid JSON",
\end{minted}
\end{column}
\hfill
\begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{minted}{json}
  "but": "this is not!"
}
\end{minted}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Is there any way to avoid this, or to let Minted know that the second part is the continuation of the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with this would probably be to put the code in an external file (or a temp file, as in the example below) and then input the different segments at the appropriate points.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}

\begin{VerbatimOut}{minted.tmp}
{
  "this": "is valid JSON",
  "but": "this is not!"
}
\end{VerbatimOut}

\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
\inputminted[firstline=1,lastline=2]{json}{minted.tmp}
\end{column}
\hfill
\begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
\inputminted[firstline=3,lastline=4]{json}{minted.tmp}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you :) As a follow-up, could this technique improve compilation times when you've got a lot of independent code snippets? i.e., Group them altogether (making sure the syntax is fine, so some tweaks may be necessary) and then `\inputminted` them, modulo the lines you are interested in? (Kind of like how CSS sprites work.)

Comment: @Xophmeister The best thing you can do for compilation times (if you haven't already) is to use the last release of `minted` (2.0), which caches output and thus removes most of the package overhead on later compiles. Using a single file for lots of snippets would save some caching checksum calculations, which might be noticeable under XeTeX. But using a single longer file also means that the entire thing would be read in each time, with all of the irrelevant lines thrown away. And it would prevent effective caching; any change would cause everything to be highlighted again.